# Dynamic change of the name of included use case in use case tagged values specification in Visual Paradigm

Tags: use-case-diagram, visual-paradigm

I am working with Visual Paradigm use-case diagrams, and I got stuck with an interesting problem. Let's say, that we have two use cases, I will denote them as "Main use-case" and "Included/Extended use-case", and If I open the specification of the Main case, and I want to write into the value of some tagged value (created by me) the command: include(the_name_of_extended_use_case) (or extend...). And also I connect these two cases with the include/extend relationship oriented line. And my question is: What if I change the name of the extended use-case from "Extend use-case") to "New use-case")?

I was looking anywhere on websites, but found nothing, and when I do this change/modifiction of name, and look into the tagged value specification of the "Main use-case", there is is still the previous name "Included/Extended use-case". So, how to make it more automatic/dynamic/based on reference, so it would change also in the tagged value spec? ALso I only work with Visual Paradigm community edition. Thanks for help.

Comment: Well this is something, what I found, but how do I acheive it: define the tagged value in Model Element type, and have it point to the target model element. In this case the display of tagged value will be based on the name of the target model ?